# NoClassDefFoundError: com.firebase.ui.auth.google.GoogleAuthProvider

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, firebaseui

I'm using Android Studio 1.5 and trying to add Firebase UI library to my application.

I've added it to my dependencies.

For some reason I'm getting the `NoClassDefFoundError` exception.

I've read that I should add Firebase-UI jar to my 'libs' folder, but I can't find it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely your missing the Google Play Services dependency from your app's build.gradle. For reference, this is one of mine:

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
  compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
  compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.3.0'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.3.0'
}
```

[FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android) depends on `com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.3.0` for its Google authentication. For all dependencies, see [this section of the README](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#add-sdk-dependencies).

Comment: I do have it. I've tried it in another computer and I didn't get that exception.